# How to find common text form 2 column containing string vlaues?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns 'Title' that contains data like 'What is Physics ?' and another column 'Content' that contains data like 'Physics is a study of....'.
I want the common text of both like ['is','Physics']. 
This has to be done for all the rows of data. How can I achieve that using R ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('what is physics?', 'set cover is NP hard', 'abstract algebra'), 
                 col2=c('Physics is the study of...', 'Example of an NP complete problem is 3-SAT', 'linear algebra'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#       col1                col2
# 1     what is physics?    Physics is the study of...
# 2 set cover is NP hard    Example of an NP complete problem is 3-SAT
# 3     abstract algebra    linear algebra

apply(df, 1, function(x) intersect(tolower(unlist(strsplit(gsub('[^a-zA-Z\\s]+', ' ', x[1]), split=' '))), 
                               tolower(unlist(strsplit(gsub('[^a-zA-Z\\s]+', ' ', x[2]), split=' ')))))

#[[1]]
#[1] "is"      "physics"

#[[2]]
#[1] "is" "np"

#[[3]]
#[1] "algebra"
```

Comment: It says  "Error in unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", " ", x[2])), split = " ") : 
  unused argument (split = " ") "

Comment: can you please check it now? there was a typo.